# Dictionary which shows plural form?

Tags: dictionaries

I am looking for a dictionary (program / app) that tells me about the plural form of a word.

I have tried Dictionary.com, Meriam-Webster and OED but they are not.

I know if I look for media, it will tell me it's plural of "medium", but is there a dictionary which does it the other way round? Thanks

Comment: I don't know why was I given a downvote. I do face the problem and when I use it http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syntax I can't find the answer too. What's wrong with the downvote?

Comment: Those who has downvoted mind to give a reason ? Simply downvoting does not help at all

Comment: Excellent question, it is absolutely bogus that dictionaries do not include plural forms of pronunciation. Especially because, it seems to me at least, some words end in an s sound and some words end in a z sound. Also, a word like "horses" does not even get shown in many dictionaries, let alone grant your the pronunciation.

Comment: The rule for pronouncing the plural ending "-s/-es" is quite simple: if "s" follows a voiced consonant or a vowel it is pronounced /z/; if it follows an unvoiced consonant it is pronounced /s/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these dictionaries give plurals for English nouns that have irregular plurals. For example, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medium) here says "*plural* **mediums** *or* **me·dia**".

If one of these dictionaries does not explicitly give a plural for a noun, the noun has a [regular plural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Regular_plurals), meaning you add an "s" or an "es". The rule is that if a word ends in the sound /s/, /z/, /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /tʃ/ or /dʒ/, you add an "es" unless it already ends with an "e", and otherwise you add an "s".

Notice that this rule depends on the pronunciation. Words like *conch* that can be pronounced two ways (this is the only one I know of) can have two plurals: *conchs* or *conches*.

There are also rules for when you replace "y" at the end of a word by "ies", and when you just an "s", but the cases where you use "-ies"  seem to be given explicitly by most dictionaries.

Comment: Adding to this, some dictionaries (e.g. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syntax)) will list the regular plurals, too.

Comment: I am aware that Wikitionary does that but some academic just not convinced with whatever wiki, e.g. Wikipedia

Comment: I'm not the down voter ... it may have been somebody who didn't realize "regular plurals" were so complicated. I don't know what definition the dictionaries use for regular plurals ... I remember learning in grade school that you added an "es" after some set of letters, maybe "j", "s", "x", "z", "ch", "sh". This rule works fairly well (although it fails for words like *Bach* and *rendezvous*).

Comment: Also, I think mango can exist in both "mangos" and "mangoes" too

Comment: Yes, but the variation in the plural of "mango" isn't caused by differing pronunciations; that's what I meant when I said "conch" was the only one I knew.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10902/discussion-between-cherhan-and-peter-shor)

Comment: @cherhan : (1) The downvotes were possibly because the English used in your post is ungrammatical and confusing. This site is intended for those with a fair command of English – the sister site ELL is dedicated to those yet to achieve this. (2) Trust Wiktionary on plurals and don't tell any academics who haven't yet realised how much the Wiki sources have improved.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because it is not the whole story. For example,  _-y_ becomes _-ies_ unless preceded by a vowel, but this is regarded as part of the rule, not as irregularities.

Comment: @Colin: in the dictionaries I checked, they actually give explicit plurals for words ending in *-y* and *o*.

Comment: @ColinFine, it’s not _quite_ a part of the rule. ‘Monkey’ in most dictionaries has only one plural: ‘monkeys’. In some, though, both ‘monkeys’ and ‘monkies’ are considered correct. Same with ‘coney’. Conversely, ‘money’ has two plurals, but they are (mostly) used differently. Most dictionaries seems to give plurals of words ending in _-y_ explicitly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The English used in the post might not be the perfect, but I don't think it is totally not understandable (at least for most people, they don't understand). Even if it is really the case (or with some grammatical flaws), I don't think the spirit is just to downvote instead of editing it and helping the OP to understand what went wrong and improve from there. I am not here to argue, just here to learn.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have nothing against Wiki sources and I am an active contributor to wiki sites. But I will be more convinced if someone can show me some articles from top journals which gladly accept Wikipedia in the bibliography (not footnote)?

Comment: @cherhan I didn't downvote, though I struggled to make sense of what exactly you were trying to say –  especially when, as Peter says in his answer, at least some acceptable irregular plural forms are given in the dictionaries you mention. Wikipedia has a good article on plural nouns at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals . If you're worried about any of its recommendations (or those in Wiktionary), you could always check those alleged usages on the net as a whole. It's what I do.

Comment: @cherhan Also, I consider the ELL site more appropriate for helping you with grammar and disambiguation – I would certainly have edited your OP if I'd known exactly what you were trying to say. But I was afraid I'd misrepresent your actual meaning. 'They are not' - not what? These three dictionaries certainly help Peter and me to discover acceptable plural forms. 'It will tell me' - which one of the three is 'it'?